# What can I do to allow web service to make changes to registry?

Tags: c#, web-services, registrykey

I have a website with a webservice (asmx.cs) backend.

I would like the webservice to be able to make changes in the registry ('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CompanyName\SoftwareName').

I have added IIS_IUSRS as well as IIS_WPG with full control.

I have verified (via System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name) that the code is running as "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"

Platform is windows 7, IIS 7.5.

I keep getting the error: "Access to the registry key ... is denied".

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Is your webapp running in x86 or 64-bit mode?

Comment: IMHO what you attempt creates a BIG SECURITY HOLE... you should create a Windows Service which modifies the registry or whatever you need... your web-service would talk to that Windows Service to achieve whatever needs to be done...

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: its running as x86, and I just verified programatically via Environment.Is64BitProcess

Comment: Yahia... I agree... unfortunately I'm on a tight deadline and trying to avoid writing a service. Also - system runs in locked-down network so risk is limited. But I may have to go the service route...

Comment: This sounds like a good WTF candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the permissions on

```
HKLM\Software\WoW6432Node\[your company]\[your software]
```

but be carefull: this might be come a security hole.